# Bibliography preamble \bibpreamble natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, preamble

I am trying to produce some text after the "References" heading, but before the numbered references themselves. I had read that using the natbib package and the command `\bibpreamble{...insert preamble here...}` should do just that, however, I cannot get this to work.

My (abridged) code is as follows:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{library}
\bibpreamble{\ \\
For an in-depth discussion on... see
\cite{Baikie1988}, and for ... see
\cite{Cardona1978, Ley1979}.}
```

This produces the References heading, the numbered references then this block of text at the end. Placing it before the `\bibliographystyle{}` command makes this block of text appear before the References heading. It is as if the command `\bibpreamble{}` is not being recognised by LaTeX.

I have also tried using `\newcommand{\bibpreamble}{...text...}` and `\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{...text...}` but neither of these change the output. Does anybody have any experience with this kind of problem? I am trying not to introduce too many changes to the structure of my document in order to make this work, so the least "invasive" solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use

```
\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{<text of the preamble>}
\bibliography{library}
```

The content of `\bibpreamble` is printed by the command producing the bibliography, thus it should be defined before issuing the command for the bibliography.

Comment: Excellent! That has fixed my problem. Thank you very much!