# Adding a preamble to a LaTeX bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, natbib, preamble

Using package `natbib`, I'm able to add a comment just above my document's bibliography using:

`\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{Some text\ldots}`

I'm adding this command to the document's preamble, and the comment is printed.

But during complilation, I receive message :

`l.697 ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`

Which forces a manual intervention to complete the compilation.

My bibliography is as follows:

```
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\label{ch:Bibliography}
```

I have been using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71100/bibliography-preamble-bibpreamble-natbib) as a reference.

Can anyone advise?

And is it possible to order the references in the bibliography in the order they appear in the document?

A minimum worked example will follow shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the preamble but with the style for the bibliography. It is not compatible with the author-year style of `natbib`.  You can avoid it by switching to a different style or by using the numeric citation option of `natbib` (i.e., `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`). For the second part of the question (order of the references) you have to use an appropriate style. (By the way, the style is `IEEEtran` not `ieeetran`.)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use `IEEEtranN` with `natbib` package, but do remember to use package `url` which will help you in better management of URLs shown in bibliography.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as there's no reference to IEEE. I think this is better-suited as a comment.